# How to maintain a UIScrollView's contentOffset by middle center part instead of top left corner while rotating or resizing?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

A UIScrollView has a `contentOffset` property, which contains the top left corner's offset of its contents.

And when you rotate your device, or somehow change the UIScrollView's `bound.size` from other parts of your program, the contentOffset's value doesn't change, which means the top left corner of the visible content remains the same.

My question is, is there any way to keep the middle center part if the visible content while rotating or changing the UIScrollView's `bound.size` to make it look nicer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rotate your iPhone, `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method is called.

Override this method and readjust `contentOffset` to where you want to show.